ODI 12 (12c) mapping (Teradata-> MSSQL) Error
Hi, I'm stumped, the problem is this:
I’m testing work on a new server - I took the FDMEE repository as a basis and decided to add ODI scripts to it (how do you feel about such cohabitation?)
configured topology for teradata and mssql
I created a display:
teradata -> teradata - generated scenario- run = success
mssql-> mssql generated scenario– run = successful

Error in teradata → mssql generation scenario:
java.lang.RuntimeException: BIPReportLocation is not defined

It’s strange, connections to databases ping, scenarios work inside technologies, but between them it doesn’t work
I use the standard knowledge module


The problem was in the local knowledge module of data transfer from TD to MSSQL
Added it -> registered the choice in the physical mapping scheme -> it worked

The problem was in the local knowledge module of data transfer from TD to MSSQL.
Added it -> registered the choice in the physical mapping scheme -> it worked.

This answer was posted as a comment to the question (Solved) ODI 12 (12c) mapping (Teradata-> MSSQL) Error by the OP MaskNu11 under CC BY-SA 4.0.
